# Why is my Symfony site so slow? Can someone decipher this pingdom?

Tags: performance, symfony1

my site is really really slow, 4603prospect.com? Sometimes its ok, sometimes its slow. I am caching thumbnails, I dont understand what to make of this pingdom report.... http://tools.pingdom.com/?url=4603prospect.com&treeview=0&column=objectID&order=1&type=0&save=false

Thanks
Todd

Answer (score 0):

Things that might help to check:

- Are you using shared hosting? Your server may be responding slowly due to the activity on other websites on the server
- Are your images falling foul of an htaccess rule which results in redirects?
- How many images are you loading at once? Most browsers can only make ~8 http requests at a time. You could try combining some of your CSS and JS files together to limit the HTTP requests.

Comment: I have host gator baby shared hosting, and they insist the problem is not them.

How could i determine that the images may be fallng fould of an htaccess rule?

I am loading lots of images at time, perhaps there is a way to merge all of the thumbnails?

How did you post bullets?
Todd

Comment: I just opened your site in Firefox with Firebug on to track the page load and found it to be working fine. 

I wonder if Pingdom have some issues with their service. Pingdom are a very low cost monitoring service and so their may be an issue with how their report works?